# How to Refill Stack using Node Implementation

Tags: c++, stack, using, nodes, fill

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Refill Stack using Node Implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7975858/refill-stack-using-node-implementation)

I'm having a hard time refilling the stack after i take it all off in order to print it out. I am using node implementation so i think this fact is what is confusing me. Any suggestions would be appreciated, thank you.

This is my original stack::print()

```
// Function to print Gumball info field (color and counter)
void Stack::print()
{
    Node *p;
    Type x;

    while(top != NULL) {
        p = top;
        x = p -> getinfo();
        cout << " " << x.color << " " << " " << x.counter << endl << endl;
        top = p -> getnext();
    } 

    return;
}
```

This is my stack with my attempt to loop and store in temp. It compiles but still is not working as suppose to

```
void Stack::print()
{
    Node *p,*q;
    Type x,x_temp;

    while(top != NULL) {
        p = top;
        x = p -> getinfo();
        cout << " " << x.color << " " << " " << x.counter << endl << endl;
        x_temp = x;
        q = top;
        top = p -> getnext();
    }

    while(top != NULL) {
        q -> setinfo(x_temp);
        q -> setnext(top);
        top = q;
    }
    return;
}
```